# SQL: Displaying results from conditional loop

Tags: sql

I'm not even sure if this is possible using SQL only but here goes...

I have a list of football results in one table, each row is a match and contains all data from that match, I want to cycle through each match, get the home team, check their last 6 matches and display only the matches where the specified team scored 2 goals or more in 50% or more of their last 6 matches.

So far I have this, I just don't know how to stitch it together...

Create list of all games, returning only the home team:

```
SELECT Date, Home
FROM [FDATA].[dbo].[Goals]
ORDER BY Date
```

Get last 6 games of that team:

```
SELECT TOP 6 *
FROM [FDATA].[dbo].[Goals]
WHERE Home = 'home from first query'  AND Date <= 'date from first query'  
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Then check if the team scored 2 or more goals in >= 50% of the 6 games returned and output the row from the first query if true:

```
SELECT *
FROM last query
WHERE HomeGoals >= 2
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Apologies for the crudeness of this question but I'm a bit of a novice.

Comment: It might be possible with sql, but, if the data is being displayed in a .net, coldfusion, php, etc application, it would be easier to apply the conditional logic with that code.

Comment: Yeah I tried it in .net but it's too slow, I'm hoping pure SQL will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use only need two queries:

```
SELECT home, count(1) cnt
FROM 
(
     SELECT TOP 6 G1.HomeGoals, G1.Home
       FROM [FDATA].[dbo].[Goals] AS G1 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
            [FDATA].[dbo].[Goals] AS G2 ON
           G1.Home = G2.HOME  AND G1.Date <= G2.Date  
     ORDER BY G1.Date DESC    
)
WHERE HomeGoals >= 2
GROUP BY home
HAVING count(1) >= 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it doesn't work though. It says 'Home' and 'HomeGoals' are invalid column names (they are correct, it's just not picking them up for some reason?)

Comment: Can you list more info about your table structure

Comment: Yes, the columns are: GameID, Date, Home, HomeGoals, AwayGoals, Away. I already corrected the lowercase 'home' (my fault) but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? the SQL is correct....I explicitly listed the columns names..try it again :/

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: @user2096512 plz try it again with the columns names explicity listed

Comment: No it still doesn't work, the error when executing is: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'".

Comment: Try adding an alias for the subquery and see if that solve your issue

Comment: I got it working by adding an alias to the MAIN query but it doesn't do what I want it to, it only returns the last 6 games in the database.